How to Export JSON from Blender with Split Normals using Geometry Nodes
I am trying to export a JSON file from Blender and need split normals as data on vertices. I have exported a custom attribute named "norm" using geometry nodes. However, I am struggling to evaluate the graph while looping over the primitives of the geometry and appending that in normal list.
Here is my for loop block:
    h_index_to_out = {}

indices = []
positions = []
normals = []
colors = []

index = 0
for prim in bmesh_car.faces:
    for vert in prim.verts:
        h_index = vert.index
        if h_index not in h_index_to_out:
            h_index_to_out[h_index] = index
            index = index + 1
            pos = vert.co
            positions.append(pos.x)
            positions.append(pos.y)
            positions.append(pos.z)
            **#At this point I need to write that custom exported attribute on vertices**
            normal = vert.normal
            normals.append(normal.x)
            normals.append(normal.y)
            normals.append(normal.z)
    
            colors.append(1.0)
            colors.append(1.0)
            colors.append(1.0)
            
        out_index = h_index_to_out[h_index]
        indices.append(out_index)

How can I properly evaluate the geometry nodes graph to access the custom attribute "norm" and correctly export the split normals along with the vertices?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to BSE! I'm sure someone will help, but first I suggest you prepare some minimal working example: How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice, also put a screenshot of your geometry nodes in the question. Possibly a duplicate of How to get the mapping of face(vertex) index after applying geometry modifier? except there I'm reading face attribute, not vertex/corner.
